# Java Interface Inheritance and Extending

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Imagine you are working on a mature product and a new search feature is requested that is required for 50% of your product.  Now assuming you have an established interface inheritance relationship with SomeDao that you don't want to break...

```
public interface MoneyDao 
    extends SomeDao<MoneyEntity>
{
    //Operation common in much of the application
    List<MoneyEntity> findByCriteria(MoneyCriteria criteria);     
}
```

...is there a way to expose the method 'findByCriteria(..)' without repeating it in all the other places similar to MoneyDao where it's required in a cleaner way?

Bare in mind I want to avoid casting in to a new type where its used and modifying SomeDao if at all possible.

Regards,
James

Answer (score 5):

Can you break the `findByCriteria` into its own interface and extend it in `MoneyDao`?  Something like this:

```
public interface MoneyDao 
    extends SomeDao<MoneyEntity>, MoneyFinder
{
}

public interface MoneyFinder
{
    //Operation common in much of the application
    List<MoneyEntity> findByCriteria(MoneyCriteria criteria);     
}
```

Now your class(es) implementing `MoneyDao` don't need to change, but you can pass around just the `findByCriteria` using `MoneyFinder`.

Comment: OK, @Jonathon, you were faster than me on this one :-) I have no other choice than deleting my answer.

Comment: @Riduidel Multiple answers saying the same thing in a different way isn't necessarily bad :)

Comment: Ah, I personnally prefer to avoid both vote dispersion and possibilties of mutual incoherence.

Comment: Yeh thought of that, but I have MoneyDao in many places and would rather not cast in to MoneyFinder or inject a new finder interface in to those clients if I can help it.  Guess I'm asking for the impossible with the current design.

Answer (score 1):

Its all depends on if you want a class that is searchable and is a Dao, in other words its if your Searchable class **must** also be a Dao. If its this case I would use a generic approach to make your Dao Searchable.

```
interface SearchableDao<Entity, Criteria> extends SomeDao<Entity> 
{
    List<Entity> findByCriteria(Criteria criteria);
}
```

Now your class can be a simple Dao or a SearchableDao. SearchableDao is also a simple Dao.

```
class MoneyDao implements SearchableDao<MoneyEntity, MoneyCriteria> 
{
    List<MoneyEntity> findByCriteria(MoneyCriteria criteria) {...} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work - but breaks the current relationship between MoneyDao and SomeDao, something I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I was thinking about adding an operation to SomeDao named getFilter() which returned a FilterDao providing access to findByCriteria(..) - it would mean I would need to throw a non supported exception where not needed though..thoughts?

Comment: @JamesC How do you mean it breaks the current relationship between MoneyDao and SomeDao?  MoneyDao is still a SomeDao.  I think either solution offered is cleaner than adding getFilter to SomeDao.  If you're not planning on making use of the more limited interface in clients that currently use MoneyDao or in new functionality, what are you trying to accomplish by segregating the findByCriteria out of MoneyDao?

Comment: @JamesC yes you could implement the search functionnality by delegating the search operation to an external object. Maybe criteria could have this responsibility? I think the problem come from the fact you are trying to generalise the search for objects of which you dont know the type.